# no active checks on server [xx.xxx.xx.xx:10051]: host [host] not monitored

Tags: network-monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am using Zabbix Active Agent to monitor hosts over the network but getting "no active checks on server [xx.xxx.xx.xx:10051]: host [host1] not monitored." errors only in one host with same exact server/agent configuration as in other hosts. I have double/triple checked the hostname and other configurations but issue has not been resolved. I believe I must have broke something while working on Zabbix templates but not sure what I did. I noticed "cannot send list of active checks to "xx.xxx.xx.xxx": host [host1] not monitored" error in Zabbix server log. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The host is disabled.

As you say that you are not using Zabbix proxy and host seems to be enabled, possible reasons that mask the problem:

- you are comparing DNS, not host name
- host has visible name defined

Make sure to compare the name agent and server print in their logfiles with the `Hostname` field in the host properties. Keep in mind that it is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi @Richlv, Thanks for your response. The host in Zabbix Server Host Configuration page is enabled. I am not understanding what you meant by "The host is disabled Filler here". If you would not mind, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Are you using Zabbix proxy to monitor this host or is it monitored directly by the server?

Comment: Hi @Richlv, I am using Zabbix Active Agent and directly monitored by the server, no proxy.

Comment: Host is still likely disabled. Please show screenshot of host configuration.